# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.bson.BSON from class com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongo-java-driver

We are trying to update our spring boot to 2.7.1.

We have old mongo java dependencies as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Code is building fine but when we are running the app in tomcat 7, we are seeing lot of beans creations exceptions Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.bson.BSON from class com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Was this issue solved?